# Multiple child in flutter

Tags: flutter

i want to add another `MaterialButton` under the first one.
I got the first `Button` and a want to add multiple ones.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 0, left: 5, right: 5),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Container(
            height: 180,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey[300],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            ),),)
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the buttons inside the `Expanded` widget to allocate space evenly within a `Row`

```
body: return SingleChildScrollView  (
        child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 0, left: 5, right: 5),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Container(
              height: 180,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              )
            ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Container(
              height: 180,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              )
            ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Container(
              height: 180,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              )
            ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: Using the code I wrote , how can I set a new row that contains 2,3 buttons ? Sorry I'm still learning here.

Comment: @JuniorDev Check the updated answer above. Use expanded inside the row, it will allocate equal width to all 3 buttons.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Add Multiple Buttons and if you want to align them horizontally, then enclose the buttons inside a Row Widget. If you want to Align them Vertically, Enclose them inside a Column Widget.

If you want to have both Horizontally and Vertically aligned Make the Parent Widget as Column and have multiple children of Row Widgets and The Row can have Buttons as children

Comment: the first button is taking all the screen width. The next 3 buttons should be aligned horizontally under the first one.